# strstream in c++

Tags: visual-c++, strstream

I am writing the code

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
strstream temp;

int t =10;
temp>>10;

string tt ="testing"+temp.str();
```

Have a problem, it does not work at all for the temp variable, just get in result only string testing without 10 in the end?

}

Comment: does this compile? strstream is defined in <strstream> not <sstream>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `operator<<()` instead, `temp << 10;`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks (to me) like a simple typo. You need to replace: `temp>>10;` with `temp<<10;`.

Comment: think i didnt do this... just some error... it should work but somehow no:(

Answer (score 0):

As you have included `sstream`, I think you had the `ostringstream` class in mind.

```
ostringstream temp;
int i = 10;
temp << i;
string tt = "testing" + temp.str();
```

To use `strstream`, include `<strstream>`. `strstream`  work with `char*`, which are C strings. Use `ostringstream` to work with objects of type `basic_string`.

Comment: nope still the same problem, could it be problem in compiler?